# How to convert date to string DD MM YYY

Tags: php

I need to convert the date from 2020-11-01 to string 01 Nov 2020

So far I could achieved like this

```
$test = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2020-11-01')->format('d m Y');
```

But the result is show `01 11 2020`
How to make the month become `Nov`?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php have a look at the php docs

Comment: Also this is surely a duplicate but there is always someone ready to copy some other (simple) answer instead to flag it as duplicate. @hawita before to post other questions please read the entire [Help Section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) focusing on [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Downvoted. Asking on this site should not be a substitute for doing basic research and reading the manual. It is trivial to find this information from the PHP website.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
date('d M Y',strtotime('2020-11-01'));
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use strtotime to get the time stamp and the use that time stamp to change format with date funtion

```
$timeStamp=strtotime("2020-11-01");
$res=date("d M Y",$timeStamp);
```